# Turn off USB power on computer shutdown, windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, power-supply, shutdown

Long story short, when computer is turned off, USB's are not, and manufacturers just love to adorn their stuff with LED lights nowadays. I want to sleep, but my room looks like a christmas party.

What I tried to do:
1. Turned off USB Suspension. Did nothing.
2. Did the "powercfg -h off" in console.
3. Made sure "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power\HiberbootEnabled" is set to 0
4. Tried to follow many advices to turn off Fast Startup in power settings, however, in my system, checkbox is just missing. All the other stuff is there, but Fast Start option isnt.

I just want stuff to turn off when I turn it off! Please, any help?
UPD: Fast Startup wasnt showing up because I turned off hibernation. Still, didnt help.

Comment: Are the USB devices self-powered?

Comment: If the power is staying on when the computer is powered off (and it's not powered externally by a separate plug, then you likely need to look in the bios for how to disable this, however without knowing the device details (specially the motherboard in this case) it's impossible to explain in any more detail.

Comment: As @djsmiley2k says, in systems I've seen USB power when the computer is off is controlled in "BIOS".

Comment: Did you check your bios/uefi for any usb settings

Comment: As other comments have mentioned, newer systems allow charging USB devices while the PC is off. This setting is generally controlled in the BIOS/EFI ([ASUS](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1042220/) & [Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000156341/usb-powershare-feature-on-dell-laptops) articles on it). Alternatively some USB hubs allow individual ports to be turned off (ex: [SABRANT](https://a.co/d/enGGTX9)) so that could be utilized

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at your BIOS. On many systems there is a option to keep the power connected on powering off. Set this to your wishes.

Comment: If you are in Europe, it may be called "ErP" - changing this can significantly reduce the standby power usage of your PC, while also disabling wake on keyboard, etc. But as a side effect, it turns all the USB ports off in standby.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want stuff to turn off when I turn it off!

It is not so simple nowadays. This depends on particular design of "a computer" and what do you mean "turn it off".

Power management in modern PCs is defined by ACPI specifications, "Advanced Configuration and Power Interface". The specification defines power and functional properties for "global states" (Gx), "system states" (Sx) and individual "device states" (Dx), and much more. Systems can have 6 power states, from S0 to S5.  Implementations of what a PC can do differ, so USB behavior can be different. See this article, [ACPI Sleep States (S0 - S5)](https://onlinehelp.ncr.com/Retail/Workstations/7613/HTML/Topics/UserGuide/5.%20Power%20Management/3-ACPI%20Sleep%20States%20(S0%20-%20S5).htm) for ACPI states overview, or many other nice articles, [this one shows](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/advanced-configuration-and-power-interface) an example of state diagram

[image]

If you have a really modern ACPI-compliant computer, you might have "allow hibernate" option, which might (I repeat, might) turn USB power OFF. This function is more likely on laptops. On simple desktops the USB power is derived from Power Supply +5VSB standby rail when PC is "soft-OFF". The +5VSB rail is "always ON", so USB power won't go away unless you disconnect you power cord from AC outlet.

Answer (score -1):

Shut down your laptop as follows:  Right click Start and select Shut down (not suspend). When OFF, unplug (as noted above) so that you do not keep the battery on AC power all the time. Everything will go OFF.

Answer (score -1):

I sorted my particular problem this way:

Windows 'says' it's shutdown and screen turns off properly, but motherboard still stays running (fans. lights usb etc).

I removed the Samsung USB drivers for Mobile (to connect my Galaxy s6 to PC) and my PC now actually does proper shutdown AND restarts!

Proved using another drive running Windows 10 on same machine but without Samsung Drivers.
Windows Event Logs and fiddling with Bios and Hiberfile / Power settings etc doesn't even come in to it, IF you use another Windows 10 fresh drive to prove these things.